# Looking for the equation or algorithm for a mystery dataset

Tags: algorithms, algebraic-curves

I'm a programmer by trade, although I did both A-level and engineering maths at University, I'm a little rusty.

I'm trying to reverse engineer a pretty shoddy bit of legacy code. I have two sets of numbers, but I'd like to understand the equation behind them.

[image: graphs]
Here are my two datasets and although I recognise the shape of both curves I can't think what type of equation they are. If someone can help me work out the generic form of the equation I can try and solve them.

It doesn't need to be done for work, so there's no rush.

Just to clarify, this is the full extent of the data I have. So unfortunately there's no way to tell if it's a repeating pattern, like a wave, half of a bell curve or some sort of decay. Fun, eh?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of inline image, I don't have enough reputation to include the image yet! Doh!

Comment: @CyberneticianDave Added it for you.

Comment: Do both sets represent the same curve (well, rotated)?

Comment: You're not helping us providing no context. Not even sample values.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, and also for the addition of the picture @DonkeyKong. I'm not sure how much information I'm able to share, as part of process of which these datasets are part may be intellectual property of the company. Apologies if that makes it confusing. I can certainly provide some of the data points, as without context they're just numbers. Let me know if that would be useful? The two datasets look related to me, but they're not exactly the same thing, as far as I know. That's part of what I'm hoping to find out.

Answer (score 3):

The green curve looks like some sigmoid function, and the blue one looks exactly the same, but just mirrored (along the first bisector) and up to translation. Mirroring along the first bisector means that you just consider the inverse function of the original.

[image]

So sigmoid functions come in many forms, you can find a lot of those as CDFs of symmetric continuous pdfs. Therefore I recommind looking at the CDFs of the

- Normal distribution (no closed form)
- Cauchy distribution (bascially the $arctan$ function)
- Laplace distribution (two $exp$ stitched together)
- Slash distribution
- Logistic distribution

More inspiration here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

If you have found a function $x\mapsto f(x)$ that resembles your data, you can easily adjust it with some basic transformations:

#### Translation:

Moving $f$ to by $p$ to the right and by $q$ upwards (negative values denote the other direction) results in

$$x \mapsto f(x-p)+q$$

Stretching $f$ by the factor $a$ in $y$-directon and $b$ in $x$-direction results in

$$ x \mapsto a f(x/b)$$

Or all together

$$ x \mapsto af((x-p)/b)+q$$

Comment: That's very interesting, because I did find myself drawn to normal distributions whilst trying to have a stab at what the curve represents. PDF = Probability Density Function, yes? What is CDF (I'll probably remember once someone tells me)?

Comment: So unlike a polynomial equation, where you can say it's some derivative of the basic form $ax^2+bx+c$, there's no easy boilerplate that I can then apply these numbers to in order to work out the equation?

Comment: Finding the *right* curve just from data is quite a difficult problem. Exactly, pdf means porbability density function and CDF is the *cumulative density function* which is basically just the antiderivative of the first. But you do not really have to care about those terms, but those sigmoid function (sigmoid=s-shaped, like yours) just appear a lot in statistics/machine learning etc.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer @flawr, and the regular updates/edits! You've given me much to think about!

Comment: Are the curves symmetrical (180° rotation) ?

Comment: @CyberneticianDave If you have followup questions feel free to ask=)

Answer (score 0):

Without any context, guessing the equations of these curves is doomed to failure. There can be many expressions producing similar curves, and without any mathematical/physical interpretation, nor any hint about the asymptotic behaviors nor symmetry, any empirical fit is meaningless.

That these curves are CDF's is highly unlikely, as their range isn't $[0,1]$, and there are few reasons to rescale them to other ranges. Pure trigonometric functions are also unlikely for similar reasons. Hyperbolic tangent is possible, but not more likely than other empirical sigmoids.

Comment: Darn. I was enjoying the challenge of trying to solve them. I was hoping that by better understanding the data I might be able to improve the process to which the two curves belong. Unfortunately the data I have is also imperfect, it's represented by whole integers. You might not see the steps in the curve, but it's not a perfect representation as it stands. Which makes the dataset itself not really good enough to determine it's equation.

Comment: Can you provide a logarithmic plot of the green curve ? (I am assuming that the $y$ axis is an asymptote.)

Comment: I could try @YvesDaoust, I'll have to work out how to get python/matlab to generate that plot for you.

Comment: @CyberneticianDave: need to know about the asymptotic behavior, hoping to distinguish inverse (arc tangent), exponential (hyperbolic tangent) or superexponential (error function) behavior; chance are high anyway that accuracy will be insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The blue one looks like part of the plot of $\tan{x}=y$ -- reflected, relocated and rescaled. The green one looks like the same, except reflected by some line of slope $-1$.